# Erro ao abrir uma nova Activity no celular - Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-activity

Bom dia pessoal!!!
Então, sou novo em programação para Android, acontece que eu criei 3 telas:

- Principal
- Categorias
- Atitude

A principal é somente para ele ir ou em Categorias ou Sair.

A Categoria ele vai escolher em qual das categorias de frases ele quer ver.

A Atitude é uma das categorias das frases que vai estar disponível.

Não estou conseguindo abrir num dispositivo virtual dentro do Android Studio, então não estou conseguindo o log durante a execução, é diretamente no celular!

Ele abre da Main para a tela Categoria, mas da Categoria para Atitude para de funcionar e fecha o app

Segue abaixo o código da principal

```
package com.example.ensapp.ensfrases;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn_Categorias = findViewById(R.id.btn_Categorias);
        btn_Categorias.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_categorias);
            }
        });
    }
    protected void finish (View view){
        finish();
    }
}
```

TelaCategoria

```
package com.example.ensapp.ensfrases;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainCategorias extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_categorias);
    }
    public void Main(View v)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela_atitude);

    }
}
```

Tela Atitude

```
package com.example.ensapp.ensfrases;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class telaAtitude extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela_atitude);
    }
    public void mainCategoria(View v)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_categorias);
    }
}
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar, pois já tem 2 dias que estou com esse problema e não consigo arrumar...

Agradeço desde já!

Activity Principal

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sample_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_Categorias"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:onClick="mainCategorias"
    android:text="Categorias"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/sample_text"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.824" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_Sair"
    android:layout_width="107dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="136dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="136dp"
    android:onClick="finish"
    android:text="Sair"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sample_text"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.232" />
```

Activity Categoria

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:onClick="Main"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.313" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:onClick="Main"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.69"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.442" />
```

Activity Atitude

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:onClick="mainCategoria"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.29" />
```

Android Manifest XML

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainCategorias" />
    <activity android:name=".telaAtitude"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Eu aconselharia neste caso o uso de Fragments, pode postar o código completo das activitys ? e se possível os arquivos XML como exemplo pois o código apresentado aparentemente são idênticos.

Comment: Como vc está rodando o app no celular? Se vc instalar via usb e manter o cabo conectado, dá pra acompanhar os logs de erro no Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que notei você está tentando abrir uma activity com um "setContentView" dentro do método OnClick, para abrir uma activity você deve:

**Seu erro:**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn_Categorias = findViewById(R.id.btn_Categorias);
    btn_Categorias.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_categorias);
        }
    });
}
protected void finish (View view){
    finish();
}
```

}

**O correto para abrir uma activity:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SuaActivity.class);
startActivity(intent); //inicia a activity
finish(); //finaliza a activity atual
```

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado, resolveu o problema!!! :) Valeu

Comment: Que bom que ajudou, marca a resposta como aceita que assim outros podem ver que funcionou!